# Baker's map is isomorphic to the $2-$sided $(1/2,1/2)$ Bernoulli Shift

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $I^{2}=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure, and let $B:I^{2}\longrightarrow I^{2}$ be the baker map defined by $$B(x,y)=\Big(2x, \dfrac{1}{2}y\Big),\ \text{if}\ 0\leq x<\dfrac{1}{2},$$ $$B(x,y)=\Big(2x-1, \dfrac{1}{2}y+\dfrac{1}{2}\Big),\ \text{if}\ \dfrac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1.$$

Then a generating partition of $B$ is $A_{0}=[0,\frac{1}{2})\times [0,1]$, and $A_{1}=[\frac{1}{2},1]\times [0,1]$.

For $\Sigma$ take the two-sided $\Big(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\Big)$ Bernoulli shift.

Now, I am trying to show that Baker's map is isomorphic to $2-$sided $\Big(\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}\Big)$ Bernoulli Shift.

A solution online suggested using this map:

> Define $\Phi:I^{2}\longrightarrow \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}},$ by $$\Phi(x,y):=(\cdots, a_{-1}, a_{0}, a_{1},\cdots),$$ where $a_{n}=i_{n}$ if $B^{n}(x,y)\in A_{i_{n}}, n\in\mathbb{Z}.$

But I don't see why we would have $$\Sigma\circ\Phi=\Phi\circ B.$$

I think it is perhaps correct that $$\Sigma(\Phi(x,y))=\Sigma(\cdots, a_{-1}, a_{0}, a_{1},\cdots)=(\cdots, a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2},\cdots),$$ but even though this is correct, I have no idea how to calculate the RHS.

Comment: That's automatic if you defined it like that (it has nothing to do with that particular Baker's map). But in terms of the binary expansions of the components one of them would be flipped.

Comment: @JohnB could you please express $\Sigma\circ \Phi$ and $\Phi\circ B$ explicitly? I am pretty new to this stuff..

Comment: My guess is that this is homework and indeed along the usual lines of basic coding. So really you need to do it yourself!

Comment: @JohnB no problem I will figure it out and update here.

Comment: @JohnB Hi, I've thought about it, so firstly $\Sigma(\Phi(x,y))=\Sigma(\cdots, a_{-1}, a_{0}, a_{1},\cdots)=(\cdots, a_{-2}, a_{-1}, a_{0},\cdots)$, then it is indeed automatic, since $\Phi\circ B$ is still $(\cdots, a_{-1}, a_{0}, a_{1},\cdots)$, but you have infinite sequence, so they are equal..

Comment: Just a small correction: the shift gives a sequence centered at $a_1$, not at $a_{-1}$. Note that $\Phi\circ B$ also translates, and it is centered as well at $a_1$.

Comment: @JohnB I am sorry that this is the key part that I don't understand. Why $\Phi\circ B$ also translates? in the definition of $\Phi$, isn't that true that $a_{n}=0$ or $1$ only depends on where $B^{n}$ lives? so why things change after I compose $\Phi$ with $B$?

Comment: A bit longer for a comment. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\Phi(B(x,y))_n=i\ \ \Leftrightarrow \ B^{n+1}(x,y)=B^n(B(x,y))\in A_i \ \Leftrightarrow \ i=a_{n+1}.
$$
That is, you get $i=a_{n+1}$, not $i=a_n$. Summing up, we have

> $$
> \Phi(B(x,y))=(\cdots a_0 \ \boxed{a_1} \ a_2\cdots)=\Sigma(\Phi(x,y))
> $$

with center at $1$, not at $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!